# Extract multiple tag values in One Jmeter Regular Expression

Tags: jmeter

I have a response which have multiple values which need to pass in the next request. How can I right a single regular expression to capture that values and pass those to next request.

```
<id>583839</id>
<Clientno>543</Clientno>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as follows:

[image]

textual representation of the settings:

- Variable: `DATA`
- Regular Expression: `(?s)<id>(\d+)</id>.*<Clientno>(\d+)</Clientno>`
- Template: `$1$$2$`

You will be able to access the extracted values as:

- `${DATA_g1}` - for `583839`
- `${DATA_g2}` - for `543`

More information:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Apache JMeter - Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. You can use a regular expression extractor for this.

Just add 2 regular expression extractor config elements to the sampler from which you would want to extract data. Specify the below expressions in them and specify a relevant variable name. The template should be $1$ in both elements.

```
<id>(.+?)</id>
<Clientno>(.+?)</Clientno>
```

The above will provide you variables with the data you need.